# how to hide a row based on date in a cell plus 1 month?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, button

I have a spreadsheet I'm using to track television program used for fundraising.  I have a button set up with a script to hide rows containing expired programs (column K) that looks at today's date.  I would like to change it to hide rows who's programs are expired as of 30 days from today.  I can't seem to get that part to work.  I copied code from a sample I found online: I know I don't need all of it but I haven't started to cull things until I get it working the way I want.

EDIT: I forgot to link to the sample spreadsheet:  https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1VIWNJqZJFgQ-JV1QrgL9etJiwb4S3p2QyUr78HC9CdE/edit?usp=sharing

```
function HideExpired() {
const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
const sheet = ss.getSheetByName('PledgePrograms');
const timezone = ss.getSpreadsheetTimeZone();
const thisMonth = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), timezone, 'yyyy-MM');
const nextMonth = thisMonth+1;
sheet.getDataRange().getValues().forEach((Column, index) => {
    const date = Column[10];
    const dateIsBeforeCurrentMonth = Object.prototype.toString.call(date) === '[object Date]'
        && Utilities.formatDate(date, timezone, 'yyyy-MM') < nextMonth;
if (dateIsBeforeCurrentMonth || status.match(/^(Done|Rejected)$/i)) {sheet.hideRows(index + `your     text`1);
}
});
}`
```

Comment: status is undefined.

Comment: Can you share a sample dummy with sample data to accurately reproduce your script?

Comment: Crikey, I did create a sample dummy and forgot to paste the link: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1VIWNJqZJFgQ-JV1QrgL9etJiwb4S3p2QyUr78HC9CdE/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I liked the approach taken by both answers I've received neither of them worked quite right in my sheet and I couldn't follow the logic enough to correct them (likely because I forgot to post the link to my sample spreadsheet.)  I did more google searches and came up with this script that worked for me.

```
function HideExpired () {
   var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("PledgePrograms");
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  for(var i = 7; i < data.length; i++) {
    //If column C (3rd column) is "Y" then hide the row.
    if(data[i][11] === "True") {
      sheet.hideRows(i + 1);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To make this simpler, why not create a helper column in the spreadsheet, instead of computing thru Google Sheet?

[Helper Column if expired.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zG4iU.png)

Use the column as reference to hide the row. You can schedule it daily then.

```
function hideExpired() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet4")
  const xpired = ss.getRange("L2:L100").getValues()
  xpired.forEach((f,i)=>{
    if(f[0]){
      
        let rangeToHide = ss.getRange("A"+(i+2))
         ss.hideRow(rangeToHide)
    }
  })
}
```

- the range will return VALUES parsed as [[true],[false]] and etc.
- Use forEach loop and just check if the value is TRUE then just hide the row.

Comment: I like this concept.  I've been messing with it, but aren't familiar enough with the scripting to understand some of what you're doing and merely copying and pasting into my spreadsheet isn't working.  I put a link to a small sample of my larger sheets above, I forgot to include it last week.  Specific questions:

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
function HideExpired() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sheet = ss.getSheetByName('PledgePrograms');
  const timezone = ss.getSpreadsheetTimeZone();
  const dt = new Date();
  const next = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(dt.getFullYear(), dt.getMonth() + 1), dt.getDate()).valueOf();
  let d = 0;
  sheet.getDataRange().getValues().forEach((row, index) => {
    const date = new Date(row[10]);
    const dateIsBeforeCurrentMonth = date.valueOf() < next;
    if (dateIsBeforeCurrentMonth || status.match(/^(Done|Rejected)$/i)) {
      sheet.hideRows(index + 2 - d++);
    }
  });
}
```

You with have to fix status first because it's currently undefined and I'm assuming you data begins on line 2 and date is from column 11.  You cannot compare Date() objects numerically without using valueOf() or getTime()